# Obtain GET and POST arguments

Tags: get, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, http-post

Since I am learning about HTTP packets and chrome extension, I thought of developing an extenison which could extract the GET and POST arguments of a website?

Is it possible using chrome extension?

Comment: btw u have to start accept answers coz lot of ppl spent time helping u  and its ur choice to repay them back

Comment: If you're doing this as a learning exercise that's fine, but I hope you realize that Chrome has this functionality built-in to the Developer tools (`Ctrl+Shift+I`) with the **Network** tab. This always you to track all requests. [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore) is a nightmare to get users on for the majority of extensions/apps so it's just a warning if you're planning on dedicating a lot of time to this.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**GET** is embedded data in the URL

**Example : http://stackoverflow.com?username=user782400**

```
?username=user782400 is a GET request ..
```

You can fetch the data in `URL's username`

in **POST**
where data is posted back to server , using forms ... you need to know to field names which are posted to fetch the data.

---

Best thing is Use [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) `jQuery.get()` to **GET**

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

**POST**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: The provided code does not "extract the GET and POST arguments", it just request a resource using AJAX. It's not what user782400 asked.